# Processing Guarantees for Custom Sink Functions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Do custom sinks provide at-least once guarantees in flink?

I am trying to write messages to an external sink and flink doesn't provide any out-of-the-box connectors for it. Will a custom sink function which implements the checkpointed function provide at-least once guarantees?